# Routes in Restify

Tags: node.js, restify

I'm trying to define in routes in a separate file and try to do something like below (which I did in my other project):

```
switch (event.httpMethod) {
    case 'GET':
        switch(path) {
            case '/cases':
                Case.getCases(event, context, callback);
                break;
        }
        break;

    case 'POST':
        switch(path) {
            case '/cases':
                Case.createCase(event, context, callback);
                break;
        }
        break;

    case 'PATCH':
        switch(path) {
            case '/cases/{case_id}':
                Case.updateCase(event, context, callback);
                break;
        }
        break;
}
```

I tried dumping the server object but couldn't figure out how can I get the HTTP Method and the Requested Path from the server object.

What can I try next?

### Update

I'm using Restify and the code above wasn't in Restify but another NodeJS application running on AWS Lambda.

Comment: Are you using `express`? This does not look like `express` code.

Comment: I'm using restify. I removed the "express" tag

Comment: why would you want to do it? doesn't restify already have it built-in? I don't think I understand your question very well

Comment: I haven't come across any such built-in way of routing with restify? Mind sharing link?

Comment: This, for example: http://restify.com/docs/server-api/#get

Comment: @MahendraLiya On the migration guide you can also see some examples: http://restify.com/docs/6to7/

Comment: @ThalesMinussi I don't see how the content in the link is similar to the way I wish to structure the routes. The link shows the classic way of declaring the routes.

Comment: And that's why I said I didn't understand your question. WHY do you want to manually do the routing if the framework already does it for you?